# Contant timer delays the thread more than is set

Tags: timer, jmeter

I have the Test plan where is 10 requests. Just requests without Contant timer takes about 18 seconds. When I add one Contant timer with 1000 miliseconds delay after the third request It takes about 28 seconds.

Is It problem of the JMeter or I'm doing something wrong?

I'm running at Ubuntu - ElementaryOS with JMeter v. 2.11 r1554548.

I'm testing another server not mine laptop.

At Jmeter test plan I'm using Cache, Cookie manager and Request Defaults at the begin. One request with POST action. And Summary report, Graph results, View results in Table a Simple data writer at the end of test plan.

Everything is in one thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order of timer object has no impact and does not mean it executes where it is located.
In fact it will apply to every child request of the parent of timer.

Read this:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html

> 4.10 Scoping Rules

Comment: Great! Thanks @PMD UBIK-INGENIERIE
Answer is right here.
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules